# dictonary as a param in a post request in python

Tags: python, dictionary, post, parameters, request

How may I pass a dictonary as a parameter in a post request in python as a json object?
i.e
myparams = {
"userid":"datta",
"Mybooks":{'Title1':'ABC','Title2':'XYZ'}
};

I tried passing
myList = {'Title1':'ABC','Title2':'XYZ'}
myparams = {
"userid":"datta",
"Mybooks":"myList"
};

This did NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

`data` param.

```
requests.post("your url", data={key1: value1, key2: value2})
```

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Answer (score 0):

To `POST` a Json data, use `json=` parameter, eg:

```py
import requests

payload = {"userid": "datta", "Mybooks": {"Title1": "ABC", "Title2": "XYZ"}}
requests.post(url, json=payload)
```